# URDF File - robot jumps and makes small leaps

Tags: navigation, odometry, urdf, ros-kinetic, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to create a robot with two driving wheels and two caster wheels.  As shown in this image :

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

I d’not know if it is well showen in the picture, the robot has two caster wheels (front and rear).

I have create the URDF file that describes the robot, unfortunately I have some small problems that I do not know how to fix them.

URDF file link : https://gist.github.com/hdd-robot/2d334c53aaa3b7366b96249964bbfead

The problem is that the robot jumps and makes small leaps, which makes the odometry imprecise and it is very unpleasant.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321326/urdf-file---robot-jumps-and-makes-small-leaps/) by [hdd-robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40920/hdd-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-17**:
Please attach your images directly to the question. I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, the problem comes from the acceleration that is too much.
I also create a separate links for front caster wheel and back caster wheel.
Here new  files : [URDF file link](https://gist.github.com/hdd-robot/28f128aa1ee8025fb3934cfe85701937)

---

Originally posted by [hdd-robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40920/hdd-robot/) with karma: 11 on 2019-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0